# python qt, display text/label above another widget(phonon)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, widget, pyside

I'm making a video player using PySide which is a python bind to the Qt framework. I'm using phonon(a module) to display the video and I want to display text above the video as a subtitle. How can I put another widget above my phonon widget. Is opengl an option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just create your label and set the phonon widget as the parent, the label should appear over it.

```
QLabel *label = new QLabel(phononWidget);
label->setText("Text over video!");
```

(I realize this is C++ and you are working in Python but it should be similar)

**Update:**
The above will not work for hardware accelerated video playback. An alternative that does work is to create a graphics scene and add the video widget or player to the scene and use a `QGraphicsTextItem` for the text. Setting the viewport to a `QGLWidget` will enable hardware acceleration:

```
QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);

Phonon::VideoPlayer *v = new Phonon::VideoPlayer();
v->load(Phonon::MediaSource("video_file"));

QGraphicsProxyWidget *pvideoWidget = scene->addWidget(v);

QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView(scene);
view->setViewport(new QGLWidget); //Enable hardware acceleration!

QGraphicsTextItem *label = new QGraphicsTextItem("Text Over Video!", pvideoWidget);
label->moveBy(100, 100);

v->play();
```

Comment: Also note that since the label won't be in a layout, you'll need to manage its positioning manually.

Comment: Ok I put

self.label = QtGui.QLabel("Hello, this is the subtitle", self.videoWidget)

But it appears like a black box

Comment: This works for most ordinary widgets. I suppose being a video widget, there may be some hardware acceleration or overlay stuff going on that makes things a little trickier. I haven't used the phonon stuff, I'll take a look at the docs and suggest something else if I find anything.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an option that works. I tried it here but you lose hardware acceleration :(

Comment: Do you think it'll be possible to do what you're saying but to use it with opengl to access the ardwareacceleration?

Comment: I tried that. After creating the graphics view you can add view->setViewport(new QGLWidget), and you get hardware acceleration back but the label becomes a black box again. Unless somebody knows a way to easily overlay a label with video, you may have to try something more involved with the video streams.

Comment: hm ok, what do you think of displaying the text with opengl textures or freetype/bitmap fonts, do you think that will work?

Comment: It might. That's venturing past my direct experience :)

Comment: I got it working after all by using a QGraphicsTextItem instead of trying to add a QLabel to the scene. I'm updating my answer.