# I cant paint QVideoWidget with QPainter

Tags: qt, phonon, qpainter

I am trying to draw strings while I have a video palying, like a subtitle...
I have a Phonon::QVideoWidget, in its constructor I do:

```
painter = new QPainter(this);
```

and I have overrided the paint event to this, only for test:

```
void MyVideoWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
    painter->drawLine(0, 0, 1, 1);
    //painter-> anything shows
}
```

So when I start my player I see nothing that QPainter did, only the normal video playing
any ideas?

Comment: set a visible pen color wrt background for painter and try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more common to make the `QPainter` a local instance in the `paintEvent()` function.

```
QPainter painter(this);
```

This results in the `begin()` and `end()` methods being called automatically. These are necessary for the `QPainter` to work correctly. You could try calling them manually in the `paintEvent()` to see if that makes a difference.

Another thing you might try for overlaying text on the video is to create a `QLabel` in code and make your video widget its parent. This does not require sub classing the video widget or overriding the paint event.

Comment: ...and your suggestion about a QLabel let's you override its paintEvent, so you can make your own drawings, independently from the video widget.

Comment: I tryed to use QPainter local instance but didnt work either. I am begining to think that VideoWidget does not use PaintEvent to render the video...I will try to use the QLabel instead and will post here again if it worked and mark you answer, thanks

Comment: It worked, but with the tranparent background´s QLabel is not repainting when the VideoWidget changes the frames itself, Im pretty sure now that VideoWidget does not use paintEvent to render the video...any idea on how to make the subtitle label repaint itself when video is playing ?? Using a Timer would not be a good idea, would it ? thanks

Comment: You can try yet another method that worked for me in this answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3692993/31044